# TypeError: this.props.chooseVideo is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a React Video player to work. I want to change the video when the inputs are clicked, but I get the following error...

TypeError: this.props.chooseVideo is not a function

Can anyone out there please advise???

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e) {
  const text = e.target.value;
  this.props.chooseVideo(text);
}

  render() {   
    return (
      <form onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input type="radio" name="src" value="fast" /> fast
        <input type="radio" name="src" value="slow" /> slow
        <input type="radio" name="src" value="cute" /> cute
        <input type="radio" name="src" value="eek" /> eek
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the app.js code

```
const VIDEOS = {
  fast: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-fast.mp4',
  slow: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-slow.mp4',
  cute: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-cute.mp4',
  eek: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-eek.mp4'
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { src: VIDEOS.fast };

    this.chooseVideo =      this.chooseVideo.bind(this);
  }

    chooseVideo(newVideo) {
        this.setState({
        src: VIDEOS[newVideo]
    });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Video Player</h1>
        <Menu chooseVideo={this.choosevideo}/>
        <Video src={this.state.src} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the component?

Comment: where are chooseVideo function?

Comment: Should chooseVideo be a function?

Comment: Looks like your problem is lower case video in `<Menu chooseVideo={this.choosevideo}/>`